# sql stored proc syntax

Tags: sql

What is the difference when I write my parameters like this? I believe the bottom proc says set the default value to null. The top gives me an error:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'. Must declare the scalar variable

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_Part]
    @AssessmentPartId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @assessmentPartCode VARCHAR(4) NULL,
    @assessmentPartCode VARCHAR(4) NULL
AS
    SET @AssessmentPartId = NEWID()
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblEMISAssessmentPart (AssessmentPartId, 
AssessmentPartcode, AssessmentPartCode)
    VALUES (@AssessmentPartId, @assessmentPartCode, 
@assessmentPartCode)
GO
```

vs

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Create_Part]
    @AssessmentPartId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
    @assessmentPartCode VARCHAR(4) = NULL,
    @assessmentPartCode VARCHAR(4) = NULL
AS
    SET @AssessmentPartId = NEWID()
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblEMISAssessmentPart (AssessmentPartId, 
AssessmentPartcode, AssessmentPartCode)
    VALUES (@AssessmentPartId, @assessmentPartCode, 
@assessmentPartCode)
GO
```

Comment: Sproc parameters are always nullable. The `NULL` and `NOT NULL` clauses are not valid for them. The second syntax gives them a default, allowing you to not specify them in calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the nullability of a TSQL stored procedure parameter.  They are always nullable.  That's what the first bit appears to be doing.

You can assign defaults for stored procedure prameters, which makes them optional.  That's what the second bit is doing.

The second procedure can be called with just one parameter, eg

```
exec [dbo].[Create_Part] @AssessmentPartId out
```

Comment: Well that one has duplicate arguments.  If you make them unique it will compile, but you have to specify all three parameters to call the procedure.